# how to solve the error "Require statement not part of import statement" in using storybook?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I'm using storybook in vue.js.

I tried to import my component but it was failed, because Sass which imported in my component made error.

(component which is not importing Sass can imported and displayed.)

so, I check official description and created a `.storybook/main.js` file to add Sass support.

But i faced a unexpected error, "Require statement not part of import statement" in using storybook" at `const path = require('path')`.

I couldn't find example of this error related storybook, so i'm confusing.

how to solve this error?

I just started using storybook, so i don't know which file info is needed to solve this.

if need other file info, I'll add it.

My main.js

```
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async ( config ) => {
   // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

[official description of using scss in storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/)